# How to add additional handlers to an existing connection?

Tags: javascript, signalr

Within my MVC 5 application, I am setting up a Signal R connection on the client end upon page load, this works as expected.

At some point later on I want add an additional handler and make a server side call, I can see that the server recieves this call which then initiates some client side calls, the handlers at the client don't get invoked.

**Connection setup upon page load**

```
function initialiseRealTimeDataRetrieval() {
    var hub = $.connection.autoGeneratedProxyForHub;

    hub.client.recieveRealTimeData = function (data) {
        //Do Stuff
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        hub.server.getRealTimeData();
    });
}
```

**Additional calls made later on**

```
function initialiseFeed () {
    var hub = $.connection.autoGeneratedProxyForHub;

    hub.client.recieveRealTimeDataFeed = function (data) {
        //Do stuff
    };

    if ($.connection.hub.state == $.connection.connectionState.connected) {
            hub.server.getRealTimeDataFeed();
    }
    else {
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            hub.server.getRealTimeDataFeed();
        });
    }
}
```

So far I have tried the following:

- Made sure that calls made from the client to server are being invoked on the server.
- Made sure that the additional calls are work as expected if they were made along with the calls and handlers executing upon page load.
- Reviewd documentation to see if a connection must be restarted to register the new handlers.
- Attempted various methods of restarting the connection after new handlers were added

The below works as expected for the additional calls however makes everything done for the connection upon page load redundant:

```
function initialiseFeed () {
    var hub = $.connection.autoGeneratedProxyForHub;

    hub.client.recieveRealTimeDataFeed = function (data) {
        //Do stuff
    };

    $.connection.hub.stop();
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
       hub.server.getRealTimeDataFeed();
    });
}
```

Inspecting the hub object through the debugger does show that all clients are connected, including the additional ones.

Comment: Have you tried to declare your hub outside your functions and then only declare it once, and then use it each time you need to add a new client? And mybe you need to make a stop + start each time you add a new client..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Signal R JS API [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client), the automaically generated proxy for the hub can't be used to register multiple event handler:

> **When to use the generated proxy**
>
> If you want to register multiple event handlers for a client method
>   that the server calls, you can't use the generated proxy. Otherwise,
>   you can choose to use the generated proxy or not based on your coding
>   preference. If you choose not to use it, you don't have to reference
>   the "signalr/hubs" URL in a script element in your client code.

Also to register new handlers for an existing connection, that connection must have at least one handler associated with it prior to establishing a connection, upon registering new handlers you must call `start()`:

> **Note**
>
> Normally you register event handlers before calling the start method
>   to establish the connection. If you want to register some event
>   handlers after establishing the connection, you can do that, but you
>   must register at least one of your event handler(s) before calling the
>   start method. One reason for this is that there can be many Hubs in an
>   application, but you wouldn't want to trigger the OnConnected event on
>   every Hub if you are only going to use to one of them. When the
>   connection is established, the presence of a client method on a Hub's
>   proxy is what tells SignalR to trigger the OnConnected event. If you
>   don't register any event handlers before calling the start method, you
>   will be able to invoke methods on the Hub, but the Hub's OnConnected
>   method won't be called and no client methods will be invoked from the
>   server.